Cannot create new process using JupyterChart in Altair
I have an altair chart and would like to make it interactive in the following way. When I click on a data point, I want an application to be started via its CLI, with attributes from the data point provided as arguments to the startup command. My understanding is that this should be possible using the new JupyterChart class introduced in Altair 5.3.0 - see an example here. However, following the example, when I try to run my application by making a call to subprocess.Popen in my observer callback, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?
Here's a MWE:
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

def on_click(change):
    sel = change.new.value[0]
    x_sel = df.iloc[sel]["x"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", f"'{x_sel}'"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2], "y": [1,1]})

brush = alt.selection_point("brush")

jchart = alt.JupyterChart(
    alt.Chart(df).mark_point(filled=True, size=100, stroke="black").encode(
        x=alt.X("x:Q").scale(domain=[0,3]),
        y=alt.Y("y:Q").scale(domain=[0,2]),
        color=alt.Color("x:Q").legend(None)
    )
)
jchart.selections.observe(on_click, ["brush"])
jchart

Here's my environment info:
- python 3.11.9 
- altair 5.3.0
- ipykernel 6.25.0 (required by VS Code)
- jupyter 1.0.0
- notebook 6.5.6

I tried running the MWE in both VS Code (1.91.1) and jupyter notebook. In VS Code, my editor window froze up: I could not switch focus to the terminal, and I could not right click on anything without immediately losing the context menu. In Jupyter Notebook, my window did not freeze, and I did not see any error messages in the interface or console, but I also did not see any output. In both cases, I expected to see the result of my Popen call (ie, "1" or "2") printed in the cell output.

This works for me in JupyterLab with altair-5.3.0 by adding a selection, see here since you want interactivity:
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

def on_click(change):
    sel = change.new.value[0]
    x_sel = df.iloc[sel]["x"]
    p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", f"'{x_sel}'"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2], "y": [1,1]})

brush = alt.selection_point("brush")

jchart = alt.JupyterChart(
    alt.Chart(df).mark_point(filled=True, size=100, stroke="black").encode(
        x=alt.X("x:Q").scale(domain=[0,3]),
        y=alt.Y("y:Q").scale(domain=[0,2]),
        color=alt.Color("x:Q").legend(None)
    ).add_params(
    brush)
)
jchart.selections.observe(on_click, ["brush"])
jchart

When I used .add_selection() like in that documentation, I got  AltairDeprecationWarning: 'add_selection' is deprecated. Use 'add_params' instead. & so I changed it. YMMV. Not sure why the documentation is outdated.
The click indication, 1 or 2, goes to the JupyterLab Log Console (look for Log indicator along the bottom ribbon to light up blue) as current Jupyter has a more strict handling of output that needs to be handled. But you just asked about making the process work as proof of concept here, and so this proves the process gets made if you add interactivity.
If you don't have JupyterLab, see 'Try It in JupyterLab Where I Saw It Work' below. You can follow that section to use my code and then restart the kernel and try your code in the fresh kernel there to see it wasn't just the environment.

Try It in JupyterLab Where I Saw It Work
Try it a temporary Jupyter session, where I tested without touching your system or logging in:
Go to here and click on the 'launch binder' badge.
When the session comes up open a new notebook and run the code:
%pip install altair
%pip install anywidget

Save the notebook.
Then restart the kernel and do a full refresh the browser page since Altair & anywidget output needs to interact with the page components. In Chrome on Mac, that is SHIFT+Command+R all pressed at the same time.
After the page reloads, run the code in the code block above.
